# Spring Boot request

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have the application (API-REST) simple in java with spring, the problem is that when run the application and i do request in postman to get all clients, simply not work, but the application yes have connection with the database

- Code:

  - Client class

    ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "clients")
    public class Client {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Integer id;
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;
     @Column(name = "email")
     private String email;
     @Column(name = "phone")
     private int phone;

     public Client() {
     }

     public Client(String name, String email, int phone) {
     this.name = name;
     this.email = email;
     this.phone = phone;
     }

     public Integer getId() {
     return id;
     }

     public void setId(Integer id) {
     this.id = id;
     }

     public String getName() {
     return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
     }

     public String getEmail() {
      return email;
     }

     public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    }
    ```

    }
  - ClientController class

    ```
      @RestController
      @RequestMapping("/client")
      public class ClientController {

      @Autowired
      private ClientService clientService;

      @PostMapping("/save")
      public Optional<Client> save(@RequestBody Client client){
         return clientService.save(client);
      }

      @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
      public Optional<Client> findById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
          return clientService.findById(id);
      }

      @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
      public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
         clientService.delete(id);
      }

      @GetMapping("/get")
      public List<Client> findAll(){
         return clientService.findAll();
    }
    ```

    }
- application.properties

  ```
   server.servlet.context-path=/company/api
   server.port=8080

   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/company
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=root
  ```
- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
       4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

- console

[image]

- postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://localhost:8080/client/get ? Your property of  server.servlet.context-path might not be applied. The response status of 404 indicates that the URL you are trying is not correct.

Also for starters make it as simple as possible and start adding complexity from there on.

1. Try making it work for  http://localhost:8080/test by removing @RequestMapping("/client") and removing  server.servlet.context-path=/company/api.
2. In this "/test" request just return a string "Hello World".
3. If this works you can go step by step increasing the complexity until you
   reached your final goal. This makes it much easier to detect errors you made. The simpler the steps you take the easier it gets :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem was the arquitecture of folders, i changed that then run perfect the proyect